# MySQL Slow large query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have this large query that I want to optimize, I already optimized it but it's still slow some times (>1s):

```
select count(DISTINCT if(ps15.specification in ('All Season'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count1 ,count(DISTINCT if(ps15.specification in ('Winter'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count2 ,count(DISTINCT if(ps15.specification in ('Zomer'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count3 ,count(DISTINCT if(ps15.specification in ('Winter 2012'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count4 ,count(DISTINCT if(ps15.specification in ('Zomer 2013'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count5 ,count(DISTINCT if(ps15.specification in ('Winter 2013'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count6 ,count(DISTINCT if(ps15.specification in ('Zomer 2014'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count7
from (products p)
inner join (products_to_categories p2c)
  on (p.products_id = p2c.products_id)
inner join (products_attributes pa)
  on (p.products_id = pa.products_id)
inner join (products_options_values pv)
  on (pa.options_values_id = pv.products_options_values_id)
inner join (products_stock ps)
  on (p.products_id=ps.products_id 
    and pv.products_options_values_id = ps.products_options_values_id2 
    and ps.products_stock_quantity>0)
INNER JOIN products_specifications ps15 
  ON p.products_id = ps15.products_id  
    AND ps15.specifications_id = '15'
    AND ps15.language_id = '1'
INNER JOIN products_specifications ps10 
  ON p.products_id = ps10.products_id  
    AND ps10.specifications_id = '10' 
    AND ps10.language_id = '1' 
where p.products_status = '1'
  and p2c.categories_id in (72,1,23,100,74,24,33,34,35,77,110,25,45,44,40,41,42,85,76,78,83,102,107,111,119,50,52,81,105,108,112,86,88,87,98,89,90,91,96,79,2,54,60,82,109,115,118,53,58,104,55,101,75,56,64,66,67,68,69,70,71,84,103,114,120,80,92,99,93,94,95,97,106,121)  
  AND ps10.specification in ('Meisje')  
  and products_options_values_name in ( 62,"3M/60cm","56-62","0-4 mnd","3m","0-3m","3-6m","3M","62/68","0-6m","50-62" , 68,"6M/67cm","9M/70cm","4-8 mnd","6m","3-6m","6M","62/68","0-6m" , 74,"4-8 mnd","8-12 mnd","6m","9m","6-9m","6M","9M","74/80","6-12m" );
```

the output is:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| count1 | count2 | count3 | count4 | count5 | count6 | count7 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|      1 |    289 |    193 |     49 |    192 |    240 |      0 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

explain mysql outputs:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                             | key                                 | key_len | ref                                   | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | index | PRIMARY,products_id                       | products_id                         | 5       | NULL                                  | 4539 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p2c   | ref   | PRIMARY                                   | PRIMARY                             | 4       | kikleding.p.products_id               |    1 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ps15  | ref   | products_id                               | products_id                         | 12      | kikleding.p2c.products_id,const,const |    1 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ps10  | ref   | products_id                               | products_id                         | 12      | kikleding.p.products_id,const,const   |    1 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pa    | ref   | idx_products_attributes_products_id       | idx_products_attributes_products_id | 4       | kikleding.p.products_id               |    6 |                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pv    | ref   | PRIMARY                                   | PRIMARY                             | 4       | kikleding.pa.options_values_id        |    2 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ps    | ref   | idx_products_stock_attributes,products_id | idx_products_stock_attributes       | 4       | kikleding.ps15.products_id            |    6 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

I have tried to index most of the tables, the ref still gives NULL in the first row of the explain.

It outputs 7 columns now, sometimes I need to output 50 columns.

Any advice?

Comment: What is `products_options_values_names`? Does it belong to the `products` table? If yes it might be an option to normalize your data model here so the optimizer can use a foreign key.

Comment: it belonges to product_options_values table

Comment: What is the hardware specs of your server, and are you sure your buffers are large enough? (the query is simple enough, and counting 7 x 4k rows shouldn't take very long anyways).

Comment: Xeon e5405 4x cpu @ 2.0 ghz, 6144 kb cache |  4000 memory, 3552 used , 415 free, 360 buffer, 2124 cached. should be enough right?

Answer (score 3):

`ref = NULL` only means that rows from the `p` table (i.e. `product`) are not joined against  other rows. Those rows are the first to be selected in your query, and rows from other tables are joined againt them. I would always expect the first line of `EXPLAIN` to show `ref = NULL`.

Basically, your execution plan says :

1. Extract rows from `products` matching the `WHERE` condition
2. Then extract rows `products_to_categories` matching rows from (1) on the `products.products_id` field
3. And so on for all tables

Suggested additional indexes:

- *table(columns)*
- products(product_id, products_status)
- products_specifications(products_id, specification, language_id, specifications_id)
- products_to_categories(products_id, categories_id)

The first one should help sensibly, I wouldn't expect too much from the other two.

I think the problem is with your many `COUNT(IF())`. This is hackish and the engine is not really optimised for this kind of queries. Instead, you must aim at returning a result set like this:

```
+---------------+-------+
| specification | count |
+---------------+-------+
| All Season    |     1 |
+---------------+-------+
| Winter        |   289 |
+---------------+-------+
| ...           |   ... |
+---------------+-------+
```

Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT
    specification,
    COUNT(*)
FROM products
JOIN ... -- your current JOIN list
GROUP BY specification -- this is the important bit
```

... and should be virtually instant, even without additional indexes (or perhaps on `products_specifications(products_id, specification)`)

Comment: Thank you for your input, I already indexed your suggestions. Out of 4546 rows there is only 7 rows that has status=0, I think Mysql decide not to use this index. 
Also the specification,count query didn't help much. 1.07 sec against 1.06 sec

Comment: Beware, by "`products(product_id, products_status)`" I mean a composite index (a two-column index) on `product_id` **and** `products_status` (as opposed to two separate indexes). I don't think such an index exists (your index is called `products_status`, which suggests an index whose first column is `product_status`). Try `ALTER TABLE products ADD INDEX pid_pstatus(product_id, product_status)` then check your execution plan again. But if most of your products have `product_status=1`, then this is certainly useless.

Comment: Same remark for the version with `GROUP BY`: add a composite index on `products_specifications(products_id, specification)` first.

Comment: yes i used a composite index but I didn't give it a logic name products_id=(products_id,products_status). because phpmyadmin name it like that.

Comment: Woops, eye glitch, my bad, sorry :) (I read "products_status"). Let me think about that.